# Please explain me some methods used in Ionic 2 (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I've found some Ionic 2 code [here](https://github.com/bradtraversy/ionreddit/blob/master/src/app/services/reddit.service.ts):
This code retrieves the data and parses it as JSON. It looks like this:

```
posts: any; 
constructor( public http: Http ) {
  this.http.get( 'https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/new/.json?limit=10' )
    .map( res => res.json() )
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.posts = data.data.children;
        }
    );
}
```

I don't understand two things here:

1. What's the **res** variable? Where does it come from? Is it some internal variable or something else?
2. What is the meaning of **subscribe** method? I guess it's for accessing the data which we will get, but why is it called **subscribe**?
3. What is the meaning of the **data** variable? Where did we get it?

I have not seen this kind of syntax in web technologies :)

Comment: Looks like you could use some Angular 2, Ionic 2 tutorials and learning. This kind of code is written to avoid function callback hell, which used to occur earlier. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to understand it better if we convert this TypeScript code to plain Javascript:

```
this.http.get( 'https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/new/.json?limit=10' )
.map(function(res){
    return res.json();
})
.subscribe(function(data){
    this.posts = data.data.children;
});
```

Basically, the shorthand "arrow" function (`() => {}` or `parameter => return`) are a shortcut for the more verbose anonymous (callback) functions which are usual in asynchronous Javascript code.

As you can see, the `res` variable is a parameter passed to the callback function that `.map` receives (which is called everytime a response is received, before it's being sent to the `.subscribe()` method), and `res` means "response", which is basically the response object received as plain text (JSON) from the HTTP GET request, which has a `.json()` method that allows you convert JSON to an actual Javascript object/array.

The subscribe() function is a method from an [Observable](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/index.html) (a custom class provided by the RxJs package), which is the type of object returned by .get() and then by .map(). It's like a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) except that it can return a result more than one time. The callback function you pass to the `.subscribe()` function receives `data`, which is what the `.map()` function returned, or simply, the parsed JSON of the HTTP response converted to a Javascript object/array, which you can start using right away.

Answer (score 3):

1. `res` is response from the api url used in `this.http.get`
2. `subscribe` is available on all observables, in this case only when you subscribe that request is fired
3. `data` is the result from `.map` function, which is json value of string sent by server

Read the documentation https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/

Comment: 1. But there's no any **res** variable in returned JSON string which returned that URL...

Comment: it's an argument name you can name it anything you want, `res` is shortcut for response